# Should I be filling out form W-9 for somebody I sold used equipment to?

Tags: united-states, taxes, selling

I sold about $3,500 worth of used lighting equipment to a local business last year. I'm not a business, just an individual.

I just received an email from them asking me to fill out a W9 form for them. However, I thought a W9 was only for independent contractors or people who provide a service? Do I need to fill it out?

If I do not, is there a link to an official site like IRS.gov that says why, so I could send it to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are a business. You're not a corporation. They paid you more than $600 during the year, so they're supposed to send 1099 to you and the IRS about it. They need your taxpayer certification (W9) for that. They were supposed to ask for it before they paid you, but yes - they're supposed to ask for it.

Comment: Instead of giving your Social Security number to everyone you sell to, go to the IRS web site and get an ITIN. It acts like a SS number for this purpose, but does not have the risk level your SS does.

Comment: @Joe you **cannot** get an ITIN if you're eligible for SSN. Legally, not allowed. You were probably thinking about EIN.

Comment: EIN ! Yes, sir, that's what I had in mind. And what I set up to receive legitimate payments.